# javascript getting attributes values

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I get the "width","height" and "background-image" values from the 'style' attribute using javascript ?

```
<div id="someid" class="someclass" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-image: url(https://some image.jpg);">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript :
`x.style.width;`
`x.style.height;`
`x.style.background-image;`

Jquery:
`$('#x').css('width');`
`$('#x').css('height');`
`$('#x').css('background-image');`

Answer (score 2):

You can get properties like so:

```
// To get width
$('#someid').css('width');
// To get height
$('#someid').css('height');
// To get background-image
$('#someid').css('background-image');
```